# update blank space as null using multiple case

Tags: mysql

```
update RawAddress 
set RawAddrZip = 
  case 
  When len(RawAddrZip) <= 5 
        Then right(('00000' + RawAddrZip), 5)

  When len(RawAddrZip) > 5 and len(RawAddrZip) <= 9
         Then right(('000000000' + RawAddrZip), 9)

  When len(RawAddrZip) = 0   then  NULL
  Else 

     RawAddrZip 
  End

where  RawAddressId in (210981,210982)
```

Before update

```
RawAddreessID   RawAddressZip
210981            
210982          1234
```

After Update 
The output will be

```
RawAddreessID   RawAddressZip
210981          0000 
210982          1234
```

I wanted Null instead of 0000 . Please correct my sql

Answer (score 0):

`0` is also less than `5`. Just change the order of the case

```
case 
  When len(RawAddrZip) = 0
        Then NULL
  When len(RawAddrZip) <= 5 
        Then right(('00000' + RawAddrZip), 5)

  -- or change the condition
  When len(RawAddrZip) > 0 and len(RawAddrZip) <= 5
        Then right(('00000' + RawAddrZip), 5)
```

Also you should check for invisible characters, because if enter on the first `right()` with empty string should give you five `00000` not four `0000`

add test cases like:

```
 CASE WHEN RawAddrZip = ''    THEN 'blank'
 CASE WHEN RawAddrZip IN NULL THEN 'null'
```